# How do I edit the RGBA values of a texture in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

I have a fragment shader like so:

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler;
    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord).rgba;
    }
</script>
```

and here is the JavaScript code that handles textures:

```
function handleLoadedTexture(texture) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

function initTexture(source) {
    var newTexture = gl.createTexture();
    newTexture.image = new Image();
    objectTextures.push(newTexture);
    var index = objectTextures.length - 1;
    objectTextures[objectTextures.length - 1].image.onload = function() {
        handleLoadedTexture(objectTextures[index])
    }
    objectTextures[objectTextures.length - 1].image.src = source;
}
```

the "source" parameter is just the url to the image, "example.png" could be a source. I am trying to change the color of the texture to a different one. Is it possible to just reassign every pixel in the texture to a certain color? Is it also possible to tint a texture? Can I add another parameter in the initTexture function called "color" and have that be an array of 4 values (RGBA), or 3 if the alpha channel isn't possible to edit, then use that array somehow to change the color of the texture to one solid color or tint it?

objectTextures is just an array that holds all the WebGLTextures that are created.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out something that might be ideal for what you try to accomplish. You probably know how to create a vertex buffer, like you already do for the positions of your vertices (and probably also for texture coordinates). Add an additional one for colors in your shaders.

add to your vertex shader ( however it looks like ):

```
attribute vec4 aColors; 
varying vec4 vColors; 

void main ( void ) { 
    vColors = aColors; //basically the same as you do with texture coordinates
}
```

and your fragment shader now looks like this:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;

varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord) * vColor;
}
```

Ok that's how basic per vertex colors are set up. But now comes the slightly unusual part: Instead of going through the business of setting up a buffer and filling it with colors for every vertex, as you'd usually do, you just set it to a **constant value** for all vertices, basically a "default value" used when no vertexAttribArray is enabled for that location.

```
var colorLocation = gl.getAttribLocation( yourProgram, "aColors" );
var yourColor = [1,0,1,1];
gl.vertexAttrib4fv( colorLocation, yourColor );
```

That way you can "tint" either in a constant color or a different color per vertex ( it's not the only way to accomplish *coloring stuff*, there are like infinite alternatives, but I feel doing it this way is elegant and flexible :)

Comment: Just for testing I set yourColor and colorLocation as global variables. Assigned colorLocation like you showed in the initShader section, where the program does other getAttributeLocation and getUniformLocation, changed the program to correct one, and set vertexAttrib4v(colorLocation, yourColor) in the drawScene function. I get ' WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: vertexAttrib4fv: index out of range'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, I set colorLocation to attribute 'aColors' not 'aColor' and it works! thank you!

Comment: glad I could help you out, @Mythenatical